# git pull gets Permission denied (publickey) in Intellij but works in terminal

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh

I created keys with ssh-keygen and added it to **ssh-agent**. Things works fine in terminal, but Intellij seems to run **git pull** without using keys in **ssh-agent**. Is there a way to tell intellij to check the keys in **ssh-agent**

Comment: Do you use ssh-agent from inside WSL? It is not yet supported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275823

Comment: See also the comments at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253958